# Python: Delta between two dates based on a fixed range

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to get the delta in hours between 8p.m. and 9 a.m based on a start_time and end_time.

It is like counting the delta in hours between two dates but taking only in account the hours between 8 p.m. and 9.am

for example:

```
 start_date,                end_date,              result 

 2020-10-25 10:35:30, 2020-10-25 23:35:32,         3hours and 35 minutes (start counting at 8pm)

 2020-10-25 08:14:37,  2020-10-25 20:14:37,         approx 1 hour (from 8h14 to 9am + from 8pm to 8h14 )

2020-10-25 00:00:00,  2020-10-26 00:00:00,          from 8pm to 9 am  = (4+9 = 13 hours)
```

Thank you

Comment: did you try something? a simple "brute force" approach could be to count the seconds between start and end in a loop if they fall into the specified interval

Comment: that is exactly what I did ! But using only the hours. it seems OK ! but not perfect

Comment: Not a trivial problem I'd say; I also could think of some complicated conditionals which would be more efficient... but complicated.